# AngularJS and the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around timing in AngularJS (1.6.4) and the browser.

When the webpage loads one can see HTML and CSS load first and AngularJS variables load later. That is, the browser is *not* showing the raw variables in curly braces `{{}}`, but the correctly-formatted AngularJS content - just one bit later.

I applied the `ng-cloak` directive to the `body` tag, *and* added what AngularJS [recommends](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to my CSS.

That did not resolve the flickering. So what I did was load my JS assets before my CSS assets, and vualá the trick worked and the flickering disappeared. But I read that wouldn't work in older browsers, so not perfect either.

How does asset-loading work in the browser?

Comment: [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) should do the trick: `{{ exp }}` ==> `<span ng-bind="exp"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to load the scripts first, it should be loaded after all the css and the main structure of the page (which is HTML) is rendered in your browser. If you are using ng-cloak in the body make sure to add this css part

```
.ng-cloak,[ng-cloak],[ng\:cloak] {
     display: none!important
}
```